# voila iypwidgets 'nice' loader

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

When a notebook is rendered with voila a VERY NICE loader appear when the website is being rendered by voila, which might take several seconds if the dashboard is large.

Once in the dashboard is created and launched the User might run operations that can take several seconds to compute.
I would like to run a loader on top of the dashboard indicating the user that the computer is calculating. (Floating spinning icon or whatever)

Is it possible?

If it is not possible with the floating option is 5here any ipywidget as computing indicator (loading bar or similar)

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar, but couldn't find a way to overlay an image over the controls (locking out any further interaction etc). The easiest way I found was to have an Output widget dedicated to a progress bar, and display the progress bar when a long running calculation was happening.

This works best with a 'repeating' loading bar, such as https://i.stack.imgur.com/asFzN.gif rather than one that actually displays true progress.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import time

gif_address = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_LOADING_BAR'

with open(gif_address, 'rb') as f:
    img = f.read()

#   create loading bar widget, ready to display when running long function
loading_bar = widgets.Image(value=img)

def long_running_function():
    time.sleep(2)

out = widgets.Output()
display(out)

# make sure your widgets are observing a function which includes these lines:
with out:
    display(loading_bar)
    long_running_function()
    out.clear_output()
```

Comment: This is supper great. Actually the function running does not have to be inside the Output. I would rather prefer to have a loader-widget showing the bar loading or not showing it.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to have an output widget somewhere in at the top of the dashboard like:

```
out_loader = widgets.Output()
```

Everytime a heavy function starts to run the loader is show.

```
with out_loader:
    display(loading_bar)
```

And at the end of the function

```
out_loader.clear_output()
```

I dont know if those can be written in only one line. Would be better.